# PHP- user recognition fault

Tags: php

The problem is, the name getting displayed on screen is the first name of the table
How can i tackle it and ensure that the name of the user is derived from his email ID 
stored in the table.
For ex: i first log in as 'a' with email id a@g.com
then i log in as 'b' with email id b@g.com
now when uer 'b' lands into the welcome page the page
displays hello 'a'. So this concludes that the page displays the name 
of the first user and not the second user.
Now, I want it to display b because that is the name
to the corresponding email ID b@gmail.com

ANY HELP?

```
This part loads the table------>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

mysql_select_db($database_register, $register);
$query_getUserDetails = "SELECT `First_name`, `Last_name` FROM register ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 1";
$getUserDetails = mysql_query($query_getUserDetails, $register) or die(mysql_error());
$row_getUserDetails = mysql_fetch_assoc($getUserDetails);
$totalRows_getUserDetails = mysql_num_rows($getUserDetails);
?>

This part get the info from the table----->
<?php  echo ' Welcome, ' .$row_getUserDetails['First_name'] . ' ' . $row_getUserDetails['Last_name'] ; ?>
```

Comment: where is your "WHERE" clause ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please stop using the `mysql_*` functions - **they are deprecated** - look at [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysqli.php)

**Your problem:** You don't have a `WHERE` clause in your SQL, meaning that you're always getting the entire set of users from your table. You need something along the lines of

```
SELECT First_name, Last_name FROM register 
WHERE email = '$escaped_email' LIMIT 1
  ^ This is the important part
```

Comment: whats the solution to it?

Comment: DESC LIMIT 1 gets flagged

Comment: Just spotted an error in your original code which was carried over to mine: `ORDER BY DESC` should be `ORDER BY <field> DESC` - it requires a field by which to sort. In actual fact you don't even need sorting on this query as it returns 1 row. Updated my answer.

Comment: You need to be more specific about why it's not working. My answer solves your initial question and now it seems you're having an SQL syntax problem?